# Hibernate mapping for Cart-Item relationship?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

Consider `Item` table which exists stand alone.

```
class Item {
   private int item_id;
   private String name;
   private double price;
   private int quantity;
}
```

Consider a `Cart` table which can contain multiple items

```
class Cart {
   private int cart_id;
   private List<Item> items;
}
```

What should be the correct hibernate mapping if only `Cart` contains multiple items and and `Item` cannot contain cart?

I am not able to understand for `OneToMany` why an `Item` needs to have a `Cart` associated with it. `Item` is a standalone model file which exists in the `Repository`. When we create a cart we can add some of the items based on the quantity available.

Comment: Just make a one-way relationship then, keep List<Item> in Cart, and don't keep Cart in Item.

Answer (score 0):

Your cart should contain Items. No need the have cart in item.

It will be better if you store a new instance of Item into to cart(List).
In this new instance only the *quantity* field will be different.
Example: You have 10 Pens and you add 2 pens in the cart. So now pen quantity be reduces by 2. Create a new instance of pen with `quantity = 2` and pass this new entity to cart.